# What is the purpose of the anonymous function wrapper in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery starts off wrapping all of it's code in an anonymous function:

```
(function ( window, undefined) {
   /*
   ...jquery code...
   */
}) (window);
```

I get that the function is executed immediately upon the entire script being read, but what is the purpose of the arguments? One is a global object reference, the other is a property reference.

Now, I remember that earlier in the script development, undefined actually got defined as something else (am I remembering that right?). Was that related to this?

Also, it looks like the function is being used as an operator?  Just like it is above, I don't understand the syntax of the statement at all.  Maybe there is context that would help?

Comment: It's the code from jQuery: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.js

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The wrapper does a number of things:

```
function(window,undefined)
```

provides the `window` and `undefined` variables to the function

the anonymous call `})(window);` passes the window variable to the script.

If a user overrides the window object, they will easily be able to modify the script to use the correct `window` variable i.e.:

```
(function(window,undefined){})(w);
```

The lack of a second parameter being passed sets the `undefined` variable to have a value of `undefined` which prevents a programmer from messing up jQuery by overriding `undefined`.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand (with the added reading of this: http://mpathirage.com/files/javascript_ninja/JavaScriptNinja_ch3_Article2.pdf . So, you can manipulate the window object after jQuery loads, and it won't affect the window object called into this function?

Comment: I think it would be better for an application to break, that for some foolish developer to go on thinking it is OK to assign a value to `undefined`, unless there intention is to confuse the anyone who looks at his code.

Comment: @Dexter not quite. Objects in JS are passed by reference (sort of), so modifying the window object that was passed to jQuery will still have effect on the reference that jQuery maintains to the window object, but it allows you to override the window object with some new object. i.e. `window.foo = 'bar'` will be accessible within jQuery, but `window = {foo:'bar'}` will not.

Comment: @mikerobi If you assign a value to undefined within the scope of a function, then it wouldn't hurt other scripts, right?  Plus, you could set it to something more controllable, so that when your script experiences an undefined error, creating simpler error handling.

Comment: Incidentally, ECMAScript 5 specifies that the `undefined` variable is immutable. Of course given the nature of browsers jQuery cannot assume the current version is ECMAScript 5.

Comment: @Dexter, you are correct about the scope, but imagine a language that lets you redefine the value of of `0` and suddenly `0*3 == 6`.  `undefined` has a very specific meaning, and changing its value breaks every developers expectation of how a piece of code should behave.  In my opinion, the fact that it can be redefined is a language defect.