# Question about helper.js syntax in mobile boiler plate

Tags: javascript, mobile-website, html5boilerplate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the purpose of the anonymous function wrapper in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598479/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-anonymous-function-wrapper-in-jquery)

In the helper.js file for http://html5boilerplate.com/mobile/ the script functions are wrapped  between:

```
(function(document){

     // js functions here

})(document);
```

I'm admittedly no expert at js, but haven't seen that syntax before. I wasn't able to find info about it, though it seems like it must be common. Can someone elaborate on it or direct me to some reading? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

that is an anonymous self executing function. used to encapsulate whatever variables and function you define inside so it won't pollute the global namespace and run all in that context.

Answer (score 0):

This us an anonymous function which is called or invoked immedeately to create a private scope for the main code.

The function also passes in 'document' as an argument so it can be referenced as a local variable from inside the function.